# Regex - replace word having plus or brackets

Tags: python, regex

In Python, I am trying to do

```
text = re.sub(r'\b%s\b' % word, "replace_text", text)
```

to replace a word with some text. Using `re` rather than just doing `text.replace` to replace only if the whole word matches using `\b`. Problem comes when there are characters like `+, (, [ etc` in word. For example `+91xxxxxxxx`.

Regex treats this `+` as wildcard for one or more and breaks with error. `sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat`. Same is in the case of `(` too.

Could find a fix for this after searching around a bit. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`re.escape(string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
word = re.escape(word)
text = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(word), "replace_text", text)
```

It replaces all critical characters with a special meaning in regex patterns with their escape forms (e.g. `\+` instead of `+`).

---

*Just a sidenote: formatting with the percent (`%`) character is deprecated and was replaced by the `.format()` method of strings.*